# Inserting a node in ascending order

Tags: c

I try to insert a node that contains a string to the linkedlist in ascending order. It works if the initial of first element is higher than other initials of strings. For example,

"Zeynep"

"Ceylan"

"Demir"

this way works fine.
However if the initial of first string is smaller than any initial of strings in the list, it prints nothing.

"Ali"

"Zeynep"

"Ceylan"

This corrupts.
 I traced the code but couldnt find.

```
struct friendNode
{
    char firstName[30];
    char lastName[30];
    char gender[1];
    char birthYear[10];
    struct friendNode *next;
};

struct friendRecord
{
    struct friendNode *head;
    struct friendNode *tail;
    int size;
};
void insertFriend(struct friendNode *node, struct friendRecord *list)
{
    struct friendNode *temp_node;
    temp_node = list->head;

    if(temp_node->next == NULL)
    {
        temp_node->next = node;
        list->tail = node;
    }

    else
    {
        while(strcmp(node->firstName, temp_node->next->firstName) >= 0 )
            temp_node = temp_node->next;

        if(temp_node->next == NULL)
        {
            temp_node->next = node;
            list->tail = node;
            return;
        }

        node->next = temp_node->next;
        temp_node->next = node;
    }
}
```

Comment: Show the struct friendNode and, struct friendRecord declarations.

Comment: Will `list->head` be `NULL` when the list is emtpy? Because you appear to be dereferencing a null-pointer with `if(temp_node->next == NULL)` in that case. Perhaps you want `if(temp_node == NULL) { list->head = node; list->tail = node; }` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inserting into a linked list is pretty basic stuff. Here is one way to do it:

```
void insertFriend(struct friendNode *node, struct friendRecord *list)
{
    struct friendNode *pre = NULL;
    struct friendNode *post = list->head;

    while (post && strcmp(node->firstName, post->firstName) >= 0)
    {
        pre = post;
        post = post->next;
    }
    if (pre == NULL)
    {
        list->head = node;
    }
    else
    {
        pre->next = node;
    }
    node->next = post;
    if (post == NULL)
    {
        list->tail = node;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
void insertFriend(struct friendNode *node, struct friendRecord *list)
{
    struct friendNode *temp_node;
    temp_node = list->head;

    if(strcmp(node->firstName, list->head->firstName) < 0)
    {
        node->next = list->head;
        list->head = node;
    }

    if(temp_node->next == NULL)
    {
        temp_node->next = node;
        list->tail = node;
    }

    else
    {
        while(strcmp(node->firstName, temp_node->next->firstName) >= 0 )
            temp_node = temp_node->next;

        if(temp_node->next == NULL)
        {
            temp_node->next = node;
            list->tail = node;
            return;
        }

        node->next = temp_node->next;
        temp_node->next = node;
    }
}
```

you forgot to write code to append the node at the head of list if it is going to be the first element. I have not tried because i dont have full code. try out. if still doesn't work, i request to comment.